# How to use spread operator in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hi  i have code like below,

```
async createItem(params: ItemParams, id?: any): Promise<Item> {
    const { ...fields } = params; //remove spread operator here
    try {
        const { data: any} = await this.post(`/${ITEM}/`, keysToSnakeCase(fields)); //how can i rewrite this
        //some logic
    }
}
```

now i want to remove spread operator in line

```
const { ...fields } = params;
```

how can i do this. I have tried,

```
const {fields } = params; // says fields doesnt exist on params error.
```

could someone help me with this. thanks

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? Just use `params` if you don't need to shallow clone it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `...fields` part could be redundant in this scenario. The spread operator takes all the remaining key value pairs in your object and assigns them to a new object.

In your case `fields` is by value identical to `params`.

*(Note: `fields` and `params` are equal by value, not by reference.)*

You can simply rewrite your code like this:

```
async createItem(params: ItemParams, id?: any): Promise<Item> {
    try {
        const { data: any} = await this.post(`/${ITEM}/`, keysToSnakeCase(params));
        //some logic
    }
}
```

if the `keysToSnakeCase` function modifies its properties you'll notice that your original `params` object changes.

If this is the case, you can add the spread operator back over there to create a shallow clone of the `params` object so it is not updated.

```
async createItem(params: ItemParams, id?: any): Promise<Item> {
    try {
        const { data: any} = await this.post(`/${ITEM}/`, keysToSnakeCase(...params));
        //some logic
    }
}
```

---

For more info on the spread syntax, please refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax